# Wrong url in product Details page

Tags: magento-1.9, indexing

In My site some of the product url like this way

```
http://domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/18980/s/product-name/
```

How to fix this i try to reindex in **Catalog URL Rewrites** but i got error on this

**An error occurred while saving the URL rewrite**

i tried Manual & SSH Also some error

How to fix this

```
system.log


2016-02-10T00:10:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <?xml versi                                                                                        on="1.0"?>  in /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 5                                                                                        10
2016-02-10T00:10:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():      ^  in                                                                                         /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-02-10T00:15:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: lin                                                                                        e 3: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  i                                                                                        n /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-02-10T00:15:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <?xml versi                                                                                        on="1.0"?>  in /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 5                                                                                        10
2016-02-10T00:15:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():      ^  in                                                                                         /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-02-10T00:20:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: lin                                                                                        e 3: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  i                                                                                        n /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-02-10T00:20:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <?xml versi                                                                                        on="1.0"?>  in /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 5                                                                                        10
2016-02-10T00:20:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():      ^  in                                                                                         /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-02-10T00:25:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: lin                                                                                        e 3: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  i                                                                                        n /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-02-10T00:25:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <?xml versi                                                                                        on="1.0"?>  in /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 5                                                                                        10
2016-02-10T00:25:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():      ^  in                                                                                         /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-02-10T00:30:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: lin                                                                                        e 3: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  i                                                                                        n /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-02-10T00:30:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <?xml versi                                                                                        on="1.0"?>  in /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 5                                                                                        10
2016-02-10T00:30:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():      ^  in                                                                                         /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-02-10T00:35:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: lin                                                                                        e 3: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  i                                                                                        n /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-02-10T00:35:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <?xml versi                                                                                        on="1.0"?>  in /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 5                                                                                        10
2016-02-10T00:35:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():      ^  in                                                                                         /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-02-10T12:48:52+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: lin                                                                                        e 3: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  i                                                                                        n /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2016-02-10T12:48:52+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <?xml versi                                                                                        on="1.0"?>  in /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 5                                                                                        10
2016-02-10T12:48:52+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():      ^  in                                                                                         /var/www/html/XXXX/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
```

**exception.log**

```
{main}
2016-02-01T13:09:13+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: ' in /var/www/html/XXXX/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/XXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/html/XXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/XXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', '')
#3 /var/www/html/XXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', '')
#4 /var/www/html/XXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /var/www/html/XXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /var/www/html/XXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /var/www/html/XXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /var/www/html/XXXX/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php(77): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#9 /var/www/html/XXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController->indexAction()
#10 /var/www/html/XXXX/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 /var/www/html/XXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /var/www/html/XXXX/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /var/www/html/XXXX/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /var/www/html/XXXX/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

Comment: Can you please add error log here in question?

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: Check your recently modified layout xml files. you have declared xml statement two time in same xml file.

Comment: Can you please tell me which one

Comment: I can't tell you file from this information. but i can tell you the problem is in layout xml file.

Comment: ok i will check you mean same layout two time used right?

Comment: No. you have declared xml in same file two times.
You can debug your xml following this link : https://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento-debugging-loading-blocks-layouts-and-config-files

Comment: Ok i will check

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4588/how-to-diagnose-invalid-block-type-error  check this to trace this error

Comment: @QaisarSatti i have problem in reindex and url it's related to that

Comment: this link is related to invalid block type problem

Comment: yes but i have a problem of url and index