# 'Invalid block type: Mage_Braintree_Payments_Block_Datajs'

Tags: magento-1.9, error, blocks

I'm running Magento 1.9.1.1. I have an IWD one page checkout installed with a compatible theme. I have also installed MSP multi-flat shipping.

Upon testing my site, everything works fine. However with the IWD One page checkout module activated, the site hangs on checkout when selecting a different delivery option. I have logs activated, and below is the exception error:

```
Exception error 
2016-07-10T19:20:25+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Braintree_Payments_Block_Datajs' in /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('braintree_payme...', Array)
#2 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('braintree_payme...', 'braintree_payme...')
#3 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('braintree_payme...', 'braintree_payme...')
#4 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(40): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#8 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/All/Model/Core/Layout.php(31): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#9 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Smartwave_All_Model_Core_Layout->generateBlocks()
#10 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#11 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/community/IWD/Opc/controllers/IndexController.php(155): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#12 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): IWD_Opc_IndexController->indexAction()
#13 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#14 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /home/onyxclot/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

Would someone be able to advise what is wrong and what needs to be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all this is causing by third party module.

Looking at your log tells me it's module called `Braintree`.

**What has gone wrong?**

The `addBlock`, `createBlock`, and `_getBlockInstance` methods all expect the first parameter to be a class alias string for the block. Something like `braintree/payment`. However, in your system, this string is missing.

**How to fix?**

Because it is third party module, you should contact it's developer. If you cannot reach them then you can do couple of things:

See these lines:

```
#1 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('braintree_payme...', Array)
#2 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('braintree_payme...', 'braintree_payme...')
#3 /home/onyxclot/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('braintree_payme...', 'braintree_payme...')
```

Here `_getBlockInstance`, `createBlock` and `addBlock` are having difficulty getting the right block. In another word somewhere in your system these blocks are called but they don't exist.

It could be missing `type` or typo in your layout.

When calling block, you should follow standard pattern.

Take a look this: to call `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart` you should call this way: `type="checkout/cart"`

**Check layout file of this module and also block files, if they are calling any of these method: `_getBlockInstance`, `createBlock` and `addBlock`.**

[More reading](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4588/how-to-diagnose-invalid-block-type-error)