# Home exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: '

Tags: magento-1.9

I get the error `exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: '` so no block is mentioned. Home is not loaded properly however. So kind of hard to debug this way. Complete trace is

```
2017-02-04T12:50:35+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: ' in /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
#2 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', 'content')
#3 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', 'content')
#4 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#6 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#7 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#8 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/local/Magestore/Megamenu/controllers/Adminhtml/MegamenuController.php(472): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#9 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Magestore_Megamenu_Adminhtml_MegamenuController->cacheAction()
#10 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('cache')
#11 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

Regular error log only reports an error from earlier on:

```
[Sat Feb 04 05:00:26 2017] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/js/lr_callprice/jquery.min.map
```

Any ideas how I can debug this properly?

Comment: Reading this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4588/how-to-diagnose-invalid-block-type-error as it could help it seems

Comment: Check out for the code where you have used `block` without `type`. If it's home page then it may have been used in CMS page.

Comment: Try to disable  Megamenu  module .

Comment: catalog.xml seems to have ok blocks and references. See https://gist.github.com/jasperf/5c0af79f356ebcb872712b80385a58ca @JaiminSutariya

Comment: And cms.xml https://gist.github.com/jasperf/ecbe353e1079fdff316a36209e67d252 looks OK to me too...

Comment: @rhand, in your question it's not related to catalog. xml Please look for local.xml or CMS home page for null block type.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya What do you mean by null block type? An empty <block>?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya https://gist.github.com/jasperf/0cec6664e5dbb8570fcab1c20af9f34a is local.xml.

Comment: And I do also see `[Sat Feb 04 07:08:54 2017] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] client denied by server configuration: /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/etc/local.xml` But I thought that was only related to curl security check.. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in the [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4589/50135) by alan storm, the issue is related to a block where you have not added a type for a block. e.g.

```
<block name="checkout.cart">
```

Where in your case, it seems something like this,

```
<block name="content">
```

When you find above code,
Update it with

```
<reference name="content">
```

and complete `<reference>` tag instead of `<block>` tag.

I have a [search script](https://github.com/jsutariya/Search-Script) which can be useful for finding this error in your code, 
Once you add `search.php` file in your magento root folder, run it like `yordomain.com/search.php` search for `<block name="content">` keyword in `xml` files.
 You will find the file which needs to be updated.

Comment: Did a `grep -rnw 'app/' -e "<block name="` and found 16 instances of `<block name=`. See https://gist.github.com/jasperf/3c3e1fa75eadbb869b2e29f221e28354 . So should I replace all by `reference name`? Perhaps just the `<block name="content">` in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/megamenu.xml:127`: , no?

Comment: Yes, @rhand, you are right, there is only one block which does not have a type attribute. Update that file, the error should be gone.

Comment: Well, did that. Now megamenu cache is no longer working and the homepage is still blank though. Not even getting decent errors but `File does not exist: /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/js/lr_callprice/jquery.min.map`

Comment: can you share your `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/megamenu.xml` file?

Comment: Sure. See https://gist.github.com/jasperf/d23a3fa58ece3177d5997815397cbd4e

Comment: Well there seems to be a system error: `2017-02-04T16:26:49+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'TCurrencySwitcher.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/local:/home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/community:/home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/app/code/core:/home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear')  in /home/user/prelaunch.domain.com/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94` . Error or warning.. May be the issue now..?

Comment: update in your file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/megamenu.xml`, Please replace `<block type="content"><block type="megamenu/adminhtml_cache" name="megamenu.cache" template="megamenu/cache.phtml" /> </block>` with `<reference name="content"><block type="megamenu/adminhtml_cache" name="megamenu.cache" template="megamenu/cache.phtml" /> </reference>`

Comment: Great. Mega Menu Cache is back in business. Now for final issue / error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53036/discussion-between-rhand-and-neha-raval).